I can't send log using Fluent-Bit to Loki
I'm using Fluent-Bit and Loki and Grafana
those versions is under
Fluent-Bit 2.2
Grafana 8.3.4
Loki 3.0.0
I have 2 Virtual Machine (Rockey OS 8)
the first VM is installed Loki and Grafana.
The second VM is installed Nginx and Fluent Bit.
I wanna send Nginx access log to Loki using Fluent-Bit and visualize logs in Grafana.
But Loki doesn't seem to received any logs from Fluent-Bit of the second VM. so I can't see any labels of Fluent-Bit that I configured in Grafana.
It's not a firewall issue. because when I replaced Fluent-Bit with Promtail, It worked well.
Please check my configuration and let me know that what I made wrong.
Loki of the first VM
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
  instance_addr: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

query_range:
  results_cache:
    cache:
      embedded_cache:
        enabled: true
        max_size_mb: 100

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: tsdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v13
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093

# By default, Loki will send anonymous, but uniquely-identifiable usage and configuration
# analytics to Grafana Labs. These statistics are sent to https://stats.grafana.org/
#
# Statistics help us better understand how Loki is used, and they show us performance
# levels for most users. This helps us prioritize features and documentation.
# For more information on what's sent, look at
# https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/pkg/analytics/stats.go
# Refer to the buildReport method to see what goes into a report.
#
# If you would like to disable reporting, uncomment the following lines:
#analytics:
#  reporting_enabled: false

Fluent-Bit of the second VM
[PARSER]
    Name std_nginx_parser
    Format regex
    Regex ^(?<remote>[^ ]*)(?: (?<x_forwarded_for>[^\[]*))+ \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*) (?<elapsed_time>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
    Time_Key time
    Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    Types code:integer size:integer

[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Path /data01/logs/webLog/ssl_mssgmall/access/*_access.log
    Parser std_nginx_parser
    Tag std_nginx

[OUTPUT]
    name loki
    match *
    host 10.206.21.122
    port 3100
    uri /loki/api/v1/push
    labels job=fluentbit

enter image description here
I replaced Fluent-Bit with Promtail.
It worked well.
But I wanna use Fluent-Bit.

That could be the connectivity issue, it is working for me
    [OUTPUT]
    name                   loki
    match                  *
    host                   {hostname}
    port                   3100
    labels                 Clustername=$(clusterName), namespace=$kubernetes['namespace_name'], pod_name=$kubernetes['pod_name']
    auto_kubernetes_labels on
    Retry_Limit            no_limits


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
